# Reference variables from a string in c++

Tags: c++, string

In many popular games today, there is a developer console that you can use to make key-bindings/change the way the game works. An example of this would be in Rust, you do `heli.call` where `heli` likely being a class and `call` being a function within. I would like to do something similar to this, but I don’t want to hard-code each command. Is there a way I can get the input from the console using something like `cin` and then take what the user typed, for example `x = 1` or `x 1` and set the variable like that without checking if the user actually typed it?

Comment: I don't know the environment you talk about but if you're not prepared to be very thorough when it comes to user interaction, I don't see why you'd want to use C++. If you don't check for problems - your program may self destruct. What you describe sounds like a scripting language that is more forgiving. Maybe LUA?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `std::(unordered_)map` of strings mapping to pointer-to-members, eg:

```cpp
unordered_map<string, int Object::*> vars;
vars["x"] = &Object::x;
```

And then you can do something like this:

```
string name;
int value;
Object obj; 
cin >> name >> value;
obj.*(vars[name]) = value;
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/4a4n5U)

Comment: It might be better to use [`std::unordered_map<std::string, int Object::*>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) performance-wise as there is no need for the keys to be ordered in this case.